# How to fetch template parameters using jmustache library?

Tags: java, mustache

I am trying to get all the template parameters - the parameter names inside {{}}. As an example, for this template:

> The {{pet}} chased after the {{toy}}

I'd like to get "pet" and "toy"

I am only able to use the [samskivert/jmustache library](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache) so I cannot use a different mustache library.

Is there a way to do this with jmustache so that I don't have to parse the string with a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Mustache.Visitor` Used to visit the tags in a template without executing it

Example:

```
List<String> vars = new ArrayList<>();
Template tmpl = ... // compile your template
tmpl.visit(new Mustache.Visitor() {

  // I assume you don't care about the raw text or include directives
  public void visitText(String text) {}

  // You do care about variables, per your example
  public void visitVariable(String name) {vars.add("Variable: " + name); }

  // Also makes sense to visit nested templates.
  public boolean visitInclude(String name) { vars.add("Include: " + name); return true; }

  // I assume you also care about sections and inverted sections
  public boolean visitSection(String name) { vars.add("Section: " + name); return true; }

  public boolean visitInvertedSection(String name) { vars.add("Inverted Section: " + name); return true; }
});
```

`Visitor` is available from `jmustache` version 1.15:

```
<groupId>com.samskivert</groupId>
<artifactId>jmustache</artifactId>
<version>1.15</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a mechanism for this using `Visitor` pattern https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache/issues/108#issuecomment-510071602 but it's not released yet https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache/issues/109#issue-466358322

Comment: In the meantime you could use reflection to get the variables from the Template in the _segs field.